How to get data from Azure Workflow Trigger Histories - List
I have an Azure Logic App that has failed actions (the number is too big so I won't resubmit them manually).
I tried wtih the Azure documentation to list all of the operations:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/workflow-trigger-histories/list?view=rest-appservice-2023-12-01&tabs=HTTP
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/hostruntime/runtime/webhooks/workflow/api/management/workflows/{workflowName}/triggers/{triggerName}/histories?api-version=2023-12-01
However the response seems to be limited to 30 when I do the curl request.
Even through the Azure Portal I don't get a full list, but only get 40 responses at a time:
Example
Is there a way to list all of the failed actions with 1 request only?
Thanks!

Since you have 240K failed workflow runs and you don't want to use nextLinks hundreds of times, using the Workflow Trigger Histories - List API doesn't seem to be the best approach for you.
I can suggest an alternative solution - using the Query - Get API of the Log Analytics service.
First, you need to make sure your Logic Apps send Workflow Runtime Logs to Log Analytics workspace:

This will allow you to query the LogicAppWorkflowRuntime table using REST API.
For example, to run the following Kusto query –
LogicAppWorkflowRuntime
| project _ResourceId, WorkflowName, OperationName, StartTime, EndTime, Code, Status, Error, RunId, WorkflowId, OriginRunId, ClientTrackingId
| where OperationName == "WorkflowRunCompleted"
| where Status == "Failed"
| order by StartTime desc

– you can send a request to
https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/{workspaceId}/query?query=LogicAppWorkflowRuntime%20%7C%20project%20_ResourceId%2C%20WorkflowName%2C%20OperationName%2C%20StartTime%2C%20EndTime%2C%20Code%2C%20Status%2C%20Error%2C%20RunId%2C%20WorkflowId%2C%20OriginRunId%2C%20ClientTrackingId%20%7C%20where%20OperationName%20%3D%3D%20%22WorkflowRunCompleted%22%20%7C%20where%20Status%20%3D%3D%20%22Failed%22%20%7C%20order%20by%20StartTime%20desc
– where {workspaceId} is a Workspace ID from the Properties blade in the Azure portal.
In my tests, the response contained details of tens of thousands of workflow runs.

Hope that helps.

You can add &$top=250 to the URL to get 250 items in the response instead of 30. You can't get more than 250 items in one go.
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/hostruntime/runtime/webhooks/workflow/api/management/workflows/{workflowName}/triggers/{triggerName}/histories?api-version=2023-12-01&$top=250
To get the next items, you have nextLink in your screenshot - keep sending requests to the nextLink URLs until satisfied or until there's no nextLink.
Update: You can also filter by Status = Failed by adding the following to the URL: &$filter=status eq 'Failed'
Supported Status values:

Running
Waiting
Succeeded
Cancelled
Failed

Update 2: According to Microsoft –

as a general advice you should refrain from calling the management
endpoint of the Logic App as part of your implementation, it should be
used only when needed as it consumes much memory and it caches good
amount of data into the memory for some time, which might eventually
cause memory starvation


Thanks for the idea @10p That worked, however the issue I have is that I have 240k failed actions and manually sending another request to nextLink won't do the trick.

@AleksandarHristov This is as good as it gets with this API. I provided an alternative solution in a separate answer, check it out.

To fetch the list of trigger history at once, you need to use $top in request URL.

I have 57 runs in the workflow. So I used $top=60 and got all the runs.
Used the URL in below format.

GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/hostruntime/runtime/webhooks/workflow/api/management/workflows/{workflowName}/triggers/{triggerName}/histories?api-version=2023-12-01&$top={$top}



